# Check if a user has a subscription with dj-stripe in Django templates

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'd like to have a button in many different Django templates that encourages users to subscribe to one of two dj-stripe paid plans, but I don't want to show the button to users who have already subscribed to either plan.

I know I can use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` in templates. I haven't been able to find something similar for checking if a user is subscribed to a dj-stripe plan. Is there something, and if so, what is it? If not, how can I handle this without a lot of repetition?

Comment: what's the problem with `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`?

Comment: maybe you could add an attribute `is_subscribed` to your user model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that there is [a dj-stripe solution to this](http://dj-stripe.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#customer-user-model-has-active-subscription-property) already (that I hadn't found in my Google searches).

I just added this to my extended user model:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.username

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username

@cached_property
    def has_active_subscription(self):
        """Checks if a user has an active subscription."""
        return subscriber_has_active_subscription(self)
```

And then added this to my template:

```
{% if request.user.has_active_subscription %}
    <a href="/payments/history/">Subscription History</a>
{% else %} 
    <a href="/payments/subscribe/">Upgrade to Premium Content!</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Please note: if you're logged in as staff or as a superuser, you will automatically be marked as having an active subscription.

Comment: What if I have multiple plans, like Premium, Enterprise and Starter? I need to check what type of subscription the user has

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @nnaelle that adding an `is_subscribed` attribute to your user model is a good option for ensuring that the subscribe button isn't shown to your users that are already subscribed. Adding this attribute means that, if you haven't already, you'll need to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) in your `models.py` to keep track of whether they are subscribed. This looks something like this (as in the Django docs):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    is_subscribed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The new user model can then be accessed by, say, the views in `views.py`:

```
from my_app.models import UserProfile

def index(request):
    user = request.user
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
    ...
```

You can (and might want to) avoid having to access the user profile that way, however, by making your new user model the default for your app under `settings.py` as described in the docs for [substituting custom user models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). Then after passing in the new user model to the view, you can do a check for subscription status using `{% if not userprofile.is_subscribed %}` and only show the subscription button for those who aren't subscribed:

```
{% if not userprofile.is_subscribed %}
    <div ...></div>
{% endif %}
```

Feel free to give me your feedback!